# why do sites put sensitive information on cookies?

Tags: html, cookies

I am new to web programming but not to programming and I come across the concept of cookie to keep states between different requests of same user websites/web servers use cookies?

and they put sensitive infn like user id and password on cookie on user side and that can be tampered by others?

and my question is what advantage will they get in storing information on cookie (unless they want to expose the user to others) at client other than overhead - is it not enough just to store session ID and all the other details maintained on the server?

I mean why all the issues about cookie poisoning - if the problem is such easily solvable and straight forward?

Comment: Sensitive information are never kept in cookies, they are always saved in sessions, those who keep are idiots

Comment: Looks like a question for [Security StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The tag list so large that and I don't know what is in the list and what is not - that was just my approximation - better if the site categorize it and then drill to make the choosing easier but I will improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People don't put sensitive data in cookies. They put only those things that are needed very frequently. For example a counter variable or a list of items, and that also in very encrypted form.

If you see people putting sensitive data like password in cookies, it just means they are just trying to learn things(which is **not** a bad thing).

But if you see sensitive data in cookies in actual production, then definitly there is a really very big problem with your security.

**Edit**

```
Advantages of putting data in cookies
```

Well there are several things for which the browser has to make request to servers, which can be avoided. For example you can put a url of an image or some json data which are used on multiple pages in your web-app. Also generally these things don't change very frequently, for example the `session id`. So you definitly try minimize such network requests or data that is sent over the network.

This **can** results in much faster pages for the user and reduces the load from the server.

Comment: So if no sensitive information is put on the cookie - then how do people poison a cookie - I am assuming cookie poisoning is tampering those data put on the cookie and steal them for many reasons ?

Comment: As I said data stored on clients in cookies are encrypted, but sometimes the data that is not encrypted (or data that is not encrypted with good algorithms and are easy to crack) are stolen. For example a simple integer counter to count number of attempts the user makes for some trial. In that case that counter can be changed and can be set to some value that allows more attempts that allowed. Which  is bad.